# media query not working but other media queries working

Tags: css, media-queries

im using something like this

```
   @media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 768px) {
        /* For mobile phones: */
        td{
            background-color: red !important;
        }
    }
```

if i remove the media query it works fine but when i add it , it simply doesnt work. also it doesnt show up in css properties in inspect elements. im also using other media queries and they are working fine :

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1500px) and (min-width: 1400px) {
        .left-text {
            width: 64% !important;
        }
        .right-text {
            width: 32%;
        }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 1400px) and (min-width: 1200px) {
        .left-text {
            width: 63% !important;
        }
        .right-text {
            width: 32%;
        }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 1400px)  {
        .left-text {
            width: 63% !important;
        }
        .right-text {
            width: 32%;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

as yo can see here the media query works fine.  You will need to show us your entire code base

```css
 @media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 768px) {
        /* For mobile phones: */
        td{
            background-color: red !important;
        }
    }
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>red cell</td>
</tr>
</table>
```